# LaTex performs multiple runs when compiling

Tags: compiling, texstudio

I use TexStudio to write my PhD thesis (large document), and I have set up the compiler options on: txs:///pdflatex | txs:///biber | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///pdflatex

However, when I ask TexStudio to compile my file, it runs this whole sequence (pdflatex/biber/pdflatex/pdflatex) multiple times before finally producing the pdf file. It can sometimes repeat it 6 or 7 times, with no particular error message displayed. 
Do you have any suggestion as to what is happening and how to solve this as it takes an awfully long time to run the whole document?
I am fairly new to LaTex and probably doing something wrong, so would welcome any suggestion.
My preamble is as follows (prety long sorry):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=4cm,right=2cm,bottom=3cm,headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{10pt}

\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{10pt}

\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{10pt}

\renewcommand\cftfigafterpnum{\vskip10pt\par}

\renewcommand\cfttabafterpnum{\vskip10pt\par}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}

\fancyhead[R]{Chapter \thechapter}

\fancyfoot{}

\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[font={color=blue(pigment),small},labelfont=it,bf]{caption}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{hangindent=0pt, indention=0pt,position=top,labelfont=bf,textfont=normalfont,singlelinecheck=off,justification=raggedright}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{blank}{}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{nicefrac}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\definecolor{ceruleanblue}{rgb}{0.16, 0.32, 0.75}

\definecolor{darkcerulean}{rgb}{0.03, 0.27, 0.49}

\definecolor{blue(pigment)}{rgb}{0.2, 0.2, 0.6}

\definecolor{beaublue}{rgb}{0.74, 0.83, 0.9}

\definecolor{palecornflowerblue}{rgb}{0.67, 0.8, 0.94}

\definecolor{babyblue}{rgb}{0.54, 0.81, 0.94}

\definecolor{babyblueeyes}{rgb}{0.63, 0.79, 0.95}

\chapterfont{\fontsize{28}{30}\selectfont\color{darkcerulean}}

\sectionfont{\fontsize{14}{16.8}\selectfont}

\subsectionfont{\fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont}

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}    

\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0cm}{0.5\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}


\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp, citestyle=authoryear-comp, isbn=false, url=false, doi=false, uniquelist=false ,uniquename=false, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}

\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\addbibresource{Thesis.bib}

\usepackage{setspace}

\overfullrule=2cm
```

[image: Build tab options 1]

[image: Build tab options 2]

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you ticked the repeat button?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the build tab of preferences?

Comment: @TeXnician If I did, it was not voluntary as I don't know where the repeat button is...

Comment: @samcarter I have now added the screenshots. I actually have one warning during the run of biber that says " WARN - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\laura\AppData\Local\Temp\HkUYCNkPHW\Thesis.bib_4252.utf8, line 6, warning: 173 characters of junk seen at toplevel ". I don't know if it is relevant as my document still loads the references properly though

Comment: The button I meant is the one which is green left to the field with the commands.

Comment: Off-topic: Since you're loading the `xcolor` package with the option `table`, there's no need to load the `colortbl` package separately.

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm a long time texstudio user.  I'm using xelatex, I see when I click the build toolbar button, I see  `Process started: "xelatex.exe" -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "a".tex` and `Process exited normally` 6 times. This is a bit slow, I'm not sure why those "repeat contained compilation commands" option used for. Those options are enabled by default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few things to try (in the order I think they might solve your problem)

- As already suggested by [TeXnician](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385072/latex-performs-multiple-runs-when-compiling/385096#comment953622_385072): For the `default compiler`: to make the compilation sequence non-repeatable, click on the green arrow/triangle to make it change its colour from green to grey.

[image]

- Remove the checkbox `check and update bibliography before compiling`
- decrease the number of `maximum compile repetitions` from 5 to e.g. 1
- a dirty hack: I once had the problem, that the `internal precompile` got in my way. Unfortunately just removing the command does not seem to work, so I replaced it with a quick and harmless command, on linux based systems I use `echo " "`.

[image]

---

Furthermore I suggest to not invoke `txs:///pdflatex | txs:///biber | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///pdflatex` each time you compile, but to use an automation tool like `latexmk`, `ltx2any`, ... which are smart enough to know which compilation steps are currently necessary and do only them.

Comment: What do I need to put in the `internal precompile` field if I'm using Windows OS, thanks.

Comment: @ollydbg23 Sorry, I don't use windows

Comment: I post a similar question on the texstudio's github issue: [It is possible to avoid the buildin PDF viewer hanging when compiling · Issue #159 · texstudio-org/texstudio](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/159#issuecomment-392355676), and the author gives a reply that the multiple run is by design, see his reply: `The compiler will tell at the end of the log file if an additional run is needed. We parse this information and rerun if the compiler says so. The number of reruns depends on the packages and tex commands you are using.`